# How to iterate through a list which is in another list in thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new in thymeleaf. i'm stuck in one place where i need to iterate through a list of strings which is present inside another list. For example, ihave a json like this :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54e1865423asgj086"),
        "Name" : "Carbon Utility",
        "Modified In " : "DEC 5th",
        "Imported" : "N",
        "Classification" : "Functional SW delivery",
        "Type Designation" : "Heavy Use",
        "StateList" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Create",
                        "currentStatus" : "False",
                        "stateDuration" : "336264        "
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Implement",
                        "currentStatus" : "False",
                        "stateDuration" : "1393827        "
                },
                {
                        "name" : "RampUp",
                        "currentStatus" : "False",
                        "stateDuration" : "34        "
                },
               ]
               }
```

in my Controller, i'm adding this to a object.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Search1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showEntity( @RequestParam("type") String typeNameid,Model model,HttpSession session) {
        ------ my other stuffs--------  
        ---- here i'm getting data from other html and spliting to add to model----
        model.addAttribute("resultSourceDbObject",migrationSourceDataBean.getResultSourceDbObject());

        return "wipdm/Display";
    }
```

Now, in my html page. I'm able to print the id,name and type desgination. but i'm stuck in iterating through the statelist. For each statelist i have to create a separate subfolder inside a table and need to display the name,status and duration. I'm trying this but not working.

```
<table id="example-advanced" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style=" font-size:1.1em;">
        <thead class="dark-border-bottom">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center"> Key</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">Values</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-tt-id='1'><td><span class="file">&nbsp;&nbsp;Type</span></td><td><span th:text="${resultSourceDbObject.getString('Type Designation')}"></span>  </td></tr>
            <tr data-tt-id='1'><td><span class="file">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name</span></td><td><span th:text="${resultSourceDbObject.getString('Name')}"></span> </td></tr>
            <tr data-tt-id='1'><td><span class="file">&nbsp;&nbsp;id</span></td><td><span th:text="${resultSourceDbObject.getString('_id')}"></span> </td></tr>
            <tr data-tt-id='2'><td><span class='folder'>Statelist</span></td><td></td></tr>
              <tr data-tt-id='2-1' data-tt-parent-id='2'  th:each="relresult : ${resultSourceDbObject.getString('StateList')}"><td><span class='folder' th:text="Relationship" >Relationship</span></td><td>Folder</td></tr>
              <tr data-tt-id='2-1-1' data-tt-parent-id='2-1'><td><span class='file' >name</span></td><td th:text="${relresult.getString('name')}">Release</td></tr>
              <tr data-tt-id='2-1-2' data-tt-parent-id='2-1'><td><span class='file'>currentstatus</span></td><td th:text="${relresult.getString('currentStatus')}">132456424</td></tr>
              <tr data-tt-id='2-1-3' data-tt-parent-id='2-1'><td><span class='file'>Stateduration</span></td><td th:text="${relresult.getString('stateDuration')}">16572464</td></tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anybody tell me where i'm going wrong and how to acheive this.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of object is returned by `migrationSourceDataBean.getResultSourceDbObject()` ? Could you share the class decaration ?

Comment: it is  json object only. `th:text="${resultSourceDbObject.getString('Type Designation')}"` this is giving me the expected output for the Type. My problem is in iterating the statelist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what type of object `migrationSourceDataBean.getResultSourceDbObject()` is returning, but `resultSourceDbObject.getString('StateList')` won't be returning what you need. (I guess it's just giving you the JSON?)

Assuming it's something similar to [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) you should be calling `getJSONArray()` (or similar) which will give you the nested list which you can then iterate over.